# Filename change after using "canvas.toblob()!"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cropperjs

I am using [Cropper.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs//) to send a cropped image to a server, but when I use "convtoblob(blob )" and append blob to formfile then send it to web API, original image Filename miss and according to attached image change to "blob"!

Please help me!

Part of my code is shown below:

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blobs) {
  //blobs.nam = FN;
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("up", blobs);
  $.ajax('http://localhost:51320/api/fileupload/uploadfile', {
    method: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,

    success: function(d) {
      var d;
      $alert.show().addClass('alert-success').text('Upload success');
    },

    error: function(d) {
      var d;
      avatar.src = initialAvatarURL;
      $alert.show().addClass('alert-warning').text('Upload error');
    },

    complete: function(d) {
      var d;
      $progress.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Even when I add a new property as you see "//blobs.nam = FN;" I don't get it in webAPI.
also i have got canvas-toBlob.js but any changes!

please help me!

[web api print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DPED.png)

[html page print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyt72.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can append the formdata like this

`formData.append('up', blobs, "blobs.jpg");`

Third parameter is your file name.if you want to get your old file name please just read your `input type="file"` value like this
`var yourFileName = $("#ImageFile").val().split('\\').pop();` and change the appending code to
`formData.append('up', blobs, yourFileName );`

it's tested and working fine.